# Merging SQL Spatial polygons where there is a calculated column

Tags: sql-server, merge, spatial, area, polygons

I'm having trouble getting polygons in a SQL Spatial table to merge where there is a calculated column.

The original query works great:

```
SELECT RollNumber, Geometry, geometry::UnionAggregate(Geometry_SPA.MakeValid()) AS Geometry_SPA
FROM     dbo.LegalParcel                                                
GROUP BY RollNumber, Geometry
```

It returns a set of polygons merged by their tax roll numbers.

However we want to know areas, so we added a computed column:

```
SELECT RollNumber, Geometry_SPA.STArea() AS SqMetres, Geometry, geometry::UnionAggregate(Geometry_SPA.MakeValid()) AS Geometry_SPA    
FROM     dbo.LegalParcel               
GROUP BY RollNumber, Geometry, Geometry_SPA.STArea()
```

Since this required adding Geometry_SPA to the Group By, now the polygons which are supposed to merge come back as discrete records.

I attempted to add the aggregation onto the new SqMetres column

```
columngeometry::UnionAggregate(Geometry_SPA.STArea()) As SqMetres
```

However that ends with the error ‘Operand type clash: float is incompatible with geometry’

How can I get the necessary records to merge?

Note for anyone wondering why there are two Geometry columns: It is a requirement of our GIS software.

Comment: Somewhat hard to do without some actual data, but did you try `columngeometry::UnionAggregate(Geometry_SPA).STArea() As SqMetres`? The union aggregate should return its own geometry instance which will have the `STArea()` method available to it.

Comment: Thanks Ben.  Yes it does.  Apparently I was on the wrong track altogether with the original question.  (See answer)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue traced back to some questionable polygons in the source table.  After running

update dbo.legalparcel set Geometry_SPA=Geometry_SPA.MakeValid()
where Geometry_SPA.STIsValid() = 0

I'm now getting correct results using the original computed column.